# How i detect if the user move the scroll?

Tags: javascript

How a detect if the user moves the scroll bar? If he moves up or down I should be shown an alert with a message with value of scroll position. How can I can get a postion from bottom of a HTML element, on javascript without using jquery?

Comment: Try using onscroll event.

Answer (score 0):

**Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onscroll) for an example :**

**HTML:**

```
<div onscroll="myFunction()">
```

**JS:**

```
var x = 0;
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ++x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.onscroll` function on an element (or the document body). For instance:

```
document.body.onscroll = function(){
    // console.log would be better here.
    alert(document.body.scrollTop);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrandonBroseph/ekozdnts/). :D

You can read more about `.onscroll` on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll)!